Angular getLocaleFirstDayOfWeek('en-FR') returns 0 (Sunday) as the start day of the week where as it returns 1 (Monday) for en-NL
I need to show the start day of the week based on locale and customise the date picker to show the week days. Since NativeAdaptor always returns Sunday as the week start day,  a custom adaptor is written for overriding the native getFirstDayOfWeek() method with angular provided https://angular.io/api/common/getLocaleFirstDayOfWeek. Below is the CustomAdaptor class
import { getLocaleFirstDayOfWeek } from '@angular/common';
import { Inject, Injectable, LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { NativeDateAdapter } from '@angular/material/core';
@Injectable()
export class CustomDateAdapter extends NativeDateAdapter {
  constructor(
    @Inject(LOCALE_ID) public locale: string
  ) {
    super(locale);
  }
  override getFirstDayOfWeek(): number {
    return getLocaleFirstDayOfWeek(this.locale);
  }
}

This CustomAdaptor works fine for 'nl-NL' and 'fr-FR' which returns Monday as the start day of the week. But getLocaleFirstDayOfWeek('en-FR') returns Sunday and getLocaleFirstDayOfWeek('en-NL') returns Monday. So the application is inconsistent. While comparing with the https://www.google.com/travel/flights?gl=NL 'en-NL' and 'en-FR' should return Monday as the start day of the week.
So which is the single source of truth for getting the first day of the week?. Or is there any correction required in my implementation?

En-fr is an invalid locale, check the full list of locales to use a valid one, so it fallsback to the default value which is zero (Sunday)

As per the angualar docs,
getLocaleFirstDayOfWeek(FUNCTION)

Retrieves the first day of the week for the given locale.

getLocaleFirstDayOfWeek(locale: string): WeekDay
Parameters

locale    string -> A locale code for the locale format rules to use.

Returns

WeekDay: A day index number, using the 0-based week-day index for en-US (Sunday = 0, Monday = 1, ...). For example, for fr-FR, returns 1 to indicate that the first day is Monday.

The fix will be to simply return zero always!
  override getFirstDayOfWeek(): number {
    return 0;
  }

Source Code: angular/packages/common/locales
/closure-locale.ts
Here the 8th index is firstDay of the week number of property locale_fr which is 1 (Monday)!

My question is why getFirstDayOfWeek('en-FR') is not returning Monday. Meanwhile getFirstDayOfWeek('en-NL') returns Monday. As I compare with google flights' date picker the expected behaviour is 'en-FR' and 'en-NL' should return Monday. Here it fails for 'en-FR' in my custom adaptor. My locale selection is dynamic based on customer country and language selection. So simply returning 0 or 1 always is not a solution

@suneesh that is how angular team has coded it, see the details of the source code, they have coded it as per france standards france first day of the week so it is from a reliable source that the first day of the week of france is Monday, as per their country!

@suneesh  also you can raise a github issue on angular to understand why!

I think you are not getting my question. Angular getFirstDayOfWeek('fr-FR') is Monday and it works as expected where as getFirstDayOfWeek('en-FR') is Sunday which is not expected

@suneesh en-Fr is a invalid value, so it fallbacks to default value, is my guess! also en-fr does not exist in source code! also updated my answer!

Thanks.. It should be the case! I may have to provide condition to return Monday for 'en-FR'. @Naren Murali any other suggestion to get the first day of the week based on  country and language?

@suneesh Nothing else this is the best approach, else you can return zero always to keep it consistent
